# Openshift - Cannot connect to mysql with Java

Tags: mysql, java, openshift

I am Harold and Im new in Openshift, Im using below code to connect to MySQL with java through example here 
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/no-suitable-driver-found-error,

Unfortunately, I was'nt able to make it work.

At first, it says "No suitable driver found" so I added the mysql-connector to WEB-INF/lib folder and add Class.forName("com.mysql.jdc.Driver");

Then, its not working and not showing error either.

Any help would highly appreciated

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class someClass {

    public String databaseCall() {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String myVersion = "";

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.x.xxx.x:3306/testdb"; //make sure that this database name exists;
        String user = "admin";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                myVersion = rs.getString(1);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            myVersion = ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                myVersion = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return myVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a print statement that print out `myVersion`? If yess what is the content of myVersion? You should not put the exception inb your result variable. You should log this exception and rethrow it.

Comment: By the way it is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Not com.mysql.jdc.Driver :) Just mentioning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading through this KB article on how to use the default mysql & postgresql connections provided by each Servlet or Application container: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1086-how-to-use-the-pre-configured-mysqlds-and-postgresqlds-data-sources-in-the-java